# BadMethodCallException Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save does not exist

Tags: laravel

**To update the added categories, I encounter errors that are returned to me. I think there are functions missing or I wrote badly at the level of my controller**

I got this error

**BadMethodCallException**

**Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save does not exist.**

How to solve that ?

Here is my controller CategorieController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Categorie;


class CategorieController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function ajoutercategorie(){
        return view('admin.ajoutercategorie');
    }

    public function sauvercategorie(Request $request){

        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'category_name' => 'required | max:255',
        ]);

        $categorie = Categorie::create($validatedData);

        return redirect('/ajoutercategorie')->with('status', 'La catégorie '
        .$categorie->category_name.' a été ajoutée avec succès');

    }

    public function categorie(){
        $categories = Categorie::get();
        return view('admin.categorie')->with('categories', $categories);
    }

    public function edit_categorie($id){
        $categorie = Categorie::find($id);
        return view('admin.editcategorie')->with('categorie', $categorie);
    }

    public function modifiercategorie(Request $request, Categorie $id){
        

        $categorie = Categorie::find($id);
        $categorie->category_name = $request->input('category_name');
        
        $categorie->save();

        return redirect('/categorie')->with('status', 'La catégorie a été modifiée avec succès');

    }
}
```

My categorie.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.appadmin')


@section('title')
    Catégorie
@endsection

@section('contenu')

          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Catégorie</h4>
              @if (Session::has('status'))
              <div class="alert alert-success">
                  {{Session::get('status')}}
              </div>
              @endif
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="order-listing" class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Order #</th>
                            <th>Nom de la catégorie</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        @foreach ($categories as $categorie)

                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$categorie->id}}</td>
                            <td>{{$categorie->category_name}}</td>
                            <td>
                              <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="window.location ='{{url('/edit_categorie/' .$categorie->id)}}'">Modifier</button>
                              <button class="btn btn-outline-danger">Supprimer</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        @endforeach
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


@endsection

 @section('scripts')
    <script src="Administrateur/js/data-table.js"></script>
 @endsection


</body>

</html>
```

My table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('category_name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
class CategorieController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(Categorie $categorie) {
        $this->categorie = $categorie;
    }
```

And on your method:

```
    public function modifiercategorie(Request $request, Categorie $id){
        $categorie = $this->categorie->find($id);
        $categorie->fill($request->input('category_name'));
 
        $categorie->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: It returns as an error **Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::fill does not exist.**. How to do?

Comment: find($id) or get() should return a single record, not a collection, so maybe type hinting $id as Categorie is messing things up. see if just passing $id like modifiercategorie(Request $request, $id) works

Comment: When i put this **modifiercategorie(Request $request, $id)**, it returns as an error **ArgumentCountError**
**Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\CategorieController::modifiercategorie(), 1 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 2 expected**

Comment: Do you know what causes this?

Comment: the common cause of this is not passing the id as a parameter to the route. It should be something like this:

Route::post('update/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\CategorieController@modifiercategorie');

Comment: Here is my route `Route::get('/edit_categorie/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\CategorieController@edit_categorie')->name('categories.editcategorie');
Route::post('/modifiercategorie/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\CategorieController@modifiercategorie')->name('categories.modifiercategorie');`.

Comment: Here is the action in my form to edit the name of a category `<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="POST" action="{{ route('categories.modifiercategorie', $id) }}">` and it returns me as another error that the variable $id is undefined.   Is it right ?

Comment: Normally when passing the id in the route inside form, you assign it to a key, like 'id' => $id, but if it says undefined you probably have to declare it beforehand somewhere.